# How to encode byte sequence to avoid repetitions?

Tags: encoding

There is a problem I currently cannot resolve and need help.

I have transmitter and receiver devices. Transmitter needs to transmit random byte sequence (with possible repetitions) or unknown length. The sequence can be transformed (encoded) before transmission if we need.

Receiver device receives the sequence bytewise. It strongly requires to not have repetitioned bytes in incoming sequence. Every new byte must be different from the previous received one.

The question is how to encode the input byte sequence on transmitter side to avoid repetitions in receiver incoming byte sequence?
All bytes of incoming sequence should be uniquely decoded on receiver side.

I've heard about scramblers. As I understand some of they can output byte sequence without repetitions. But is there some simpler way?

Comment: Send every second byte as inverse of previous and ignore them on receiver side.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. It's a question asking for existing algorithms. The language tags seem irrelevant. In addition, the question is open-ended. There isn't a single correct answer. This question, to me, seems off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You may want to investigate `HDLC bit-stuffing` as a possible way to encode the length by using start/end of frame bytes as well.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It's definitely a coding theory question, but that's "code" as in " Morse code", not source code. Encoding and decoding are both algorithms, yes, but coding theory is more than an algorithm question.

Comment: Does receiver have a buffer?

Comment: @Slava: Won't work. What if the second byte/octet is the inverse of the preceeding? If you mean sending the same byte twice: that is a massive waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Just to clarify, you do want to get the original byte sequence back, right? Just via some intermediate format which removes repeated sequential bytes?

Comment: Yes, I want to get original byte sequence on receiver side. Receiver works bytewise - it has "buffer" only for 1 byte.

Comment: If I send byte and following inverse byte (as Slava says) then I cannot guarantee that next byte won't be equal to inverse of the previous one.

Comment: Can you keep one extra byte in memory on receiver?

Comment: @Olaf yea wrong idea, but it can be function of 2 bytes current one and next one. Anyway that way too ineffective I think

Comment: Can you tell us why the receiver works like this? It sounds to me that you have an X/Y problem.

Comment: It's restrictions of HW I work with. There are some special service bytes added into byte stream by transmitter. Due to HW problems the only way I can determine that such service byte received is to see it's value equal to the previous byte received. That's why I need to remove all repetitions from original byte sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reserve any byte value for special purposes. I have to make transmitter transmit bytes of any value 0-255.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data as padded group of 8 bytes, with 7 bytes of data and one special byte which has 7 bits to set 0 or 1 depends if it requires corresponding data byte to be modified (xor with FF or something) to make them different than previous. Last bit is used to make this byte different than last data one.

original data:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

packet:

```
0x00 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0b01010100 <- last bit would be flipped if previous data byte is the same as this byte
```

Note: if you do not have buffer for 8 bytes you can send padding byte first keep it in register, left/right shift and process next byte based on bit value.

Comment: Bit over the top. You can just flip-flop the top bit, that's already sufficient to prevent duplicates. So `0xxxxxxx 1xyyyyyy 0yyzzzzz 1zzz....`

Comment: Yes but decoding 7bit stream into 8bit is more complex than this on embedded I think.

Comment: I'll convert it to an answer so I can address that.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you can't construct a package which would end up with a duplicate in this manner?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen as every byte in the stream can be modified I think it is possible to produce proper stream if encoder implemented properly.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. I also was thinking about adding some metainformation in byte stream. Just wanted to know some other ideas as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I can transfer data only as a byte stream. :( And I cannot use any start and stop bytes for that. The important point is how to decode the encoded bytes properly to restore original sequence.

Comment: Then @MSalters idea with using top bit should work, you will have to decode 7 bit stream to 8 bits on receiver

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the first byte, the restriction that you can't have repeat bytes means that every byte represents a 1-in-255 choice, not a one-in-256. That means you can send slightly less than 8 bits per byte (7.994353 bits)

Hence, coding theory tells us that you need to transform your 256-symbol input stream into a 255-symbol stream. You then encode this 255-symbol stream by remembering the previous byte you sent out. If the symbol you want to send is lower than the previous byte you send, you send it unmodified, else you send it +1.

The decoding algorithm is the reverse. If you receive a byte that higher than the previously received byte, subtract one.

As a simple example, consider sending `254 254 254`. The first one can be sent straight away (first symbol), the second will be sent as 255 (+1) and the next one will be 254 again. Thus the receiver sees `254 255 254`. The only byte that's higher than the preceding byte is 255, so subtract one from that to recover the initial sequence `254 254 254`.

This coding is the most efficient possible, we just have the minor challenge of mapping a random byte stream (256 symbols) to a 255-symbol stream. Remember, in this 255-symbol code, duplications *are* allowed. That's the reason why we invented it.

One easy but inefficient hack is to replace `254` with `254 0`  and `255` with `254 1`. The downside is that this effectively uses 15.998 bits for those two inputs. One difficult but perfectly space-efficient hack is to consider the whole input as a base-256 number, and convert it to base-255.

What exactly you choose probably depends on your input.

Comment: Ok. But what if there are two 255 bytes together in a sequence? The second of them must be +1. As I understand it gonna be 0. If so then it is not >= than previous one and wond't decremented on receiver side.

Comment: @JohanZigner: There can't be any 255 values in the 255-symbol stream , by definition that uses 0..254.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to just use the top bit for uniqueness, and the lower 7 bits to carry data:

`0xxxxxxx 1xyyyyyy 0yyzzzzz 1zzz....`

This encodes every 7 bytes of input as 8 bytes on the connection. On the sender, you have one bit of state to toggle between 0 and 1, and a 0-6 counter for the variable bitshifts. On the receiver, you don't even need to decode the top bit, so you just have the 0-6 counter to reverse the bit shifts. On both sides, you need to keep part of one byte as well, so you need about 2 bytes of state for this. Still, not too bad and certainly doable in an FPGA or about a dozen ARM instructions.

Comment: Agree. This will work. But will require a lot of bit operations in firmware. Unfortunately HW is not editable now.

Comment: @JohanZigner: Luckily bit operations are pretty efficient on microcontrollers. If this won't work, I'm pretty sure nothing will.

Answer (score 0):

Guys what do you think about idea to use some soft byte scrambler?
I mean some simple algorithm than will transform original byte stream into pseudo-random sequence without repetitions?

Is it possible to avoid repetitions reliably this way?

Just would like to know it as additional possible solution...